# Find all pair of nos that sum up to S

Tags: algorithm

Given an array, find all pair of nos that sum up to a given value.
There is the classic O(n) algorithm of keeping 2 pointers at the front and back and bringing them closer to find the pair. This only leads to 1 pair. What if you want all pairs.
Bonus: Find the minimum distance pair.

Can you do this in O(n).

Comment: I assume the list must be sorted for that "classic" algorithm to work. If so, then all pairs isn't much harder.

Comment: Is the array sorted?  If so, the front and back pointers algorithm will give you all the satisfactory pairs in O(n), and the last produced will have its pair of elements at minimum distance.

Comment: Yes it is sorted. Can you explain?

Comment: Let's see your attempt first.

Comment: Pairs of nos can be produced by pairs of knights-who-say-no.

Comment: This is really a homework question tagged with interview, isn't it?

Comment: And what if I don't? Wait, wait...there's a bonus. Yipee!

Answer (score 9):

```
 int arr[SIZE]; /* sorted in ascending order */

 int a = 0, b = SIZE - 1, mindist = -1, sum;
 while (a < b) {
    sum = arr[a] + arr[b];
    if (sum == TARGET) { report_pair(a, b); mindist = b - a; a++ }
    else if (sum < TARGET) a++;
    else b--;
 }

 /* minimum distance stored in mindist */
```

Comment: for the case where TARET = 10 and a[]={5,5,5,5,5} it gives answer as 4 instead of 10

Answer (score 3):

One easy and (time) efficient solution involves a hash map from integers to integers. This algorithm works by iterating through the array. On each element x, look up sum - x in the hash table and, if it exists, print (x, sum - x). Add x to the hash table, and go to the next element.

But for O(1) constant space and O(n) linear time on sorted array,below code surely works.

```
public static void printPairSums(int[] array, int sum) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    int first = 0;
    int last = array.length - 1;
    while (first < last) {
        int s = array[first] + array[last];
        if (s == sum) {
            System.out.println(array[first] + “ “ + array[last]);
            ++first;
            --last;
        } else {
            if (s < sum) ++first;
            else --last;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        Hashtable  reqNoList=new Hashtable();
        int sum=6;
        int minPair=0,i=0,count=0;
        // just remove the second condition for unsorted array
        while(i<nums.length && i<sum){
            int key=sum-nums[i];
            if(reqNoList.containsKey(nums[i])){
                Integer temp=(Integer) reqNoList.get(nums[i]);
                System.out.println("("+key+","+nums[i]+")");
                if(count==0)
                    minPair=i-temp;
                else if((i-temp)< minPair)
                    minPair=i-temp;
                count++;
            }else
                reqNoList.put(key,i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("min Distance -->"+minPair);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Source [Link](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.438205.13)

**Bit vector:**

I like this one. Have a bit vector (i.e.array of bits) of size equal to total sum.

```
1.clear all bits
2.for each element a[i] in the array
  - if bit sum-a[i] is set, return sum-a[i], a[i]
  - else, set bit a[i]
```

This will need constant storage O(n) and time complexity is O(n) in any case.

Comment: Constant storage, but that constant is one bit for every possible integer. An algorithm which requires half a billion bytes to process half a dozen integers is probably not ideal...

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you, I mean one bit for every integer. so n-th integer will be represented by n-th bit. aka we only need half a billion bits if we have half a billion integers.

Comment: In that case, storage would be O(N), checking bit `sum-a[i]` would be O(logN) at best, and your bit vector at step `i` would always contain `i` ones followed by `N-i` zeroes, regardless of what's in `a[]`.

Comment: the storage is O(n). I screwed it up in my last sentence. Correcting that but I'm not sure why you'd require O(logN) for checking bit `sum-a[i]`. For me, the bit vector is something similar to a boolean array, only using one bit of storage instead of one byte. So getting say `bitVector[sum-a[i]]` should be O(1).

Comment: Say `sum` is 4,000,000,000, and `a[]` is `{4,5,6}`. In your first iteration, you need to check `bitVector[3999999996]`. If you're not storing 2^32 bits, how do you do this lookup in O(1)?

Comment: well, since arrays are stored linearly, I'd take the array start position in memory. say x and add 3999999996*(1 bit) to this to point to the memory block(or bit in this case). Arrays data structure does this internally for you when you ask for bitVector[3999999996] More about arrays [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Arrays) but your example does show a flaw in my idea. Unnecessarily using a lot of memory when there isn't a possibility of having the sum.

Comment: It's not only when the sum is impossible; consider `sum=4000000000`, `a={1,3999999999}`. Anyway, the real problem is that you don't know ahead of time what bits you'll need to check. When you're initialising your `bitVector`, you still need to create a 4000000000th bit, even if `sum=3`, `a={1,2}`.

Comment: if the sum is why would I do that when I need at most 3 bits. I'll just use 3 bits. Did you even refer to the actual original source that I gave ? May be you should forward your over there as well.

Comment: You say "I'll just use 3 bits". But it's not up to you to decide how many bits to use. You algorithm needs to figure this out.

Comment: Algorithm asks for no of bits = sum, so I know how many bits I need.

Comment: That won't work for `sum<0`, `a[i]<=0` or `a[i]>sum`. And it's not `O(N)`, it's `O(sum)` space and `O(N+sum)` time.

Comment: It's a general case psuedocode... every algo has special cases and by O(N) I meant linear time.. it doesn't mean O(no of bits) constant time and storage. lastly, space may be O(sum) but time is O(N). You never traverse the whole bit array, you just look for a specific value. Lastly, I never said the algorithm is practical. It's just O(N) as the question asked.

Comment: Step 1 is to clear all bits. For `O(sum)` bits, this takes `O(sum)` time.

Answer (score 0):

Little amendment to coder_15 answer, to check if the next element to first is the same as first or the previous element to last is the same as last:

```
while(first<last){
    int s = arr[first] + arr[last];
    if(s == sum){
        System.out.println(arr[first] + " : " + arr[last]);
        if(arr[first] == arr[first+1] ){
            System.out.println(arr[first+1] + " : " + arr[last]);
        }
        if(arr[last] == arr[last-1] ){
            System.out.println(arr[first] + " : " + arr[last-1]);
        }
        ++first; 
        --last; 
    }

    else{
        if(s<sum){
            ++first; 
        }
        if(s>sum)
            --last;
    }
}
```